# Javascript - Multiple nested filter expressions

Tags: javascript, arrays

Have this JSON object in JavaScript that comes from an API:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Breakfast",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "id": 100,
        "label": "Cereals, Muesli",
        "items": [
          {
            "productId": "4fdddf1d-8d31-411d-a908-5edd68a775b7",
            "label": "Bircher Muesli"
          },
          {
            "productId": "000673e7-47ec-4dce-a940-ad4aacbd7d73",
            "label": "Individual Cereals"
          },
          {
            "productId": "0f739661-5531-4734-9dfd-e145b60667cc",
            "label": "Organic Porridge Oats"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 101,
        "label": "Eggs, Omelettes",
        "items": [
          {
            "productId": "6d608133-ab44-4f9d-ab8e-fc6a3f955397",
            "label": "Crushed Avocado with Soughdough Toast"
          },
          {
            "productId": "fcfe91ab-e9b1-4dc0-8c57-ffb9646e0658",
            "label": "Crushed Avocado with Crispy Bacon"
          },
          {
            "productId": "2a80e48b-76f6-4bda-abf3-ec8dc7bf1419",
            "label": "Crushed Avocado with Smoked Salmon"
          },
          {
            "productId": "ae35e949-abf3-4795-a5df-9af4250c2185",
            "label": "Egg White Omelette"
          }
        ]
      }
      ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Light Lunch",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "id": 103,
        "label": "Condiments",
        "items": [
          {
            "productId": "25503a9b-b553-4b56-a152-49e4121cf4ae",
            "label": "Butter"
          },
          {
            "productId": "c1dd9761-f170-4e6a-a7d7-5519a4213874",
            "label": "Jam"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 104,
        "label": "Yoghurts",
        "items": [
          {
            "productId": "938fed24-6d4c-e0cd-8303-0fcd42c87be4",
            "label": "Fruit Yoghurt",
          },
          {
            "productId": "62137176-0966-4424-9093-51bd7871d31b",
            "label": "Greek Yoghurt",
          },
          {
            "productId": "307e59c4-b103-43d4-988c-75ee539d5d75",
            "label": "Granola Parfait: Layers of Berries, Fruit Granola, Yoghurt & Honey",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to filter this array above with the search query (Eg: Greek) against the **items.label** property and have it returned the filtered outcome like below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Light Lunch",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "id": 104,
        "label": "Yoghurts",
        "items": [
          {
            "productId": "62137176-0966-4424-9093-51bd7871d31b",
            "label": "Greek Yoghurt",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried various implementation with filter() with nested some() as seen on StackOverflow but did not return the desired result. Currently this works but only the top level category is filtered and the nested subcategory only exist if there's a match for item.

```
var searchQuery="Greek";
var data=[]; //JSON omitted for brevity.
var result = data.filter(a=>{
    return a.subCategories.some(b=> {
        return b.items.some(c=> new RegExp(searchQuery,"i").test(c.label));
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "only the top level category is filtered and the nested subcategory only exist if there's a match for item"? What is an example of case when the result is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this, iterating first over each of the categories, then each of the subcategories, only adding the subcategory to the output if one of its items contains the search query, and then only adding the category to the output if one of the subcategories contains the search query:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Breakfast",
    "subCategories": [{
        "id": 100,
        "label": "Cereals, Muesli",
        "items": [{
            "productId": "4fdddf1d-8d31-411d-a908-5edd68a775b7",
            "label": "Bircher Muesli"
          },
          {
            "productId": "000673e7-47ec-4dce-a940-ad4aacbd7d73",
            "label": "Individual Cereals"
          },
          {
            "productId": "0f739661-5531-4734-9dfd-e145b60667cc",
            "label": "Organic Porridge Oats"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 101,
        "label": "Eggs, Omelettes",
        "items": [{
            "productId": "6d608133-ab44-4f9d-ab8e-fc6a3f955397",
            "label": "Crushed Avocado with Soughdough Toast"
          },
          {
            "productId": "fcfe91ab-e9b1-4dc0-8c57-ffb9646e0658",
            "label": "Crushed Avocado with Crispy Bacon"
          },
          {
            "productId": "2a80e48b-76f6-4bda-abf3-ec8dc7bf1419",
            "label": "Crushed Avocado with Smoked Salmon"
          },
          {
            "productId": "ae35e949-abf3-4795-a5df-9af4250c2185",
            "label": "Egg White Omelette"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Light Lunch",
    "subCategories": [{
        "id": 103,
        "label": "Condiments",
        "items": [{
            "productId": "25503a9b-b553-4b56-a152-49e4121cf4ae",
            "label": "Butter"
          },
          {
            "productId": "c1dd9761-f170-4e6a-a7d7-5519a4213874",
            "label": "Jam"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 104,
        "label": "Yoghurts",
        "items": [{
            "productId": "938fed24-6d4c-e0cd-8303-0fcd42c87be4",
            "label": "Fruit Yoghurt",
          },
          {
            "productId": "62137176-0966-4424-9093-51bd7871d31b",
            "label": "Greek Yoghurt",
          },
          {
            "productId": "307e59c4-b103-43d4-988c-75ee539d5d75",
            "label": "Granola Parfait: Layers of Berries, Fruit Granola, Yoghurt & Honey",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const searchQuery = "Greek";
const regex = new RegExp(searchQuery, "i");
const result = data.reduce((cats, cat) => {
  cat.subCategories = cat.subCategories.reduce((subs, sub) => {
    sub.items = sub.items.filter(item => regex.test(item.label));
    if (sub.items.length) subs.push(sub);
    return subs;
  }, []);
  if (cat.subCategories.length) cats.push(cat);
  return cats;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Best solution, works quite nicely. Didn't think about using the **reduce** method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a working example which returns your requested output:

```
function finder(data, query) {
  for(let i in data) {
    // return the item if the label contains the search query
    if(new RegExp(query,"i").test(data[i].label)) return data[i]

    // go deeper in subCategories if exist
    if(data[i].subCategories) {
      let sub = finder(data[i].subCategories, query)
      if(sub) {
        data[i].subCategories = [sub]
        return data[i]
      }

    // go deeper in items if exist
    } else if(data[i].items){
      let item = finder(data[i].items, query)
      if(item) {
        data[i].items = [item]
        return data[i]
      }
    }
  }
  // didn't find the search query in this branch
  return false
}

console.log(finder(data, 'Greek'))
```

with `data` your input data

Comment: I don't think you should use regex for that. If user types a dot sign, for example, they probably don't expect that to match any character. Use `a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase()` instead.